# How does Word styles apply their formatting settings?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, styles

I've created several custom styles to ease myself and quickly format many Word documents.
Later on their content will be migrated to Salesforce.

The problem is that when I copy the content formatted with my custom styles, and paste it into Salesforce editor, the formatting is lost. **This wouldn't happen when I manually format the text in Word and paste it into external editor.**

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How do the Word styles work? Do they hardcode their formatting settings to text or is Word just using them to present the content to the user inside Word, but actual formatting is not applied?
2. Any suggestion how to make it work as expected?

Comment: Here is a good document to review. Styles should go with the document in most cases.    https://shaunakelly.com/word/sharing/willmyformatchange.html

Comment: This one even better answers my questions (point 2 on direct formatting), thanks! https://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/formatoftextchanges.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a deficiency in SalesForce.

I do not know if it is  that SalesForce knows about built-in  styles or how it gets material from built-in styles and not custom styles.

Here is the article on my website: [Understanding Styles in Microsoft Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview).

### Essentially, a style is like a programming subroutine.

You apply the style and Word reads that style setting in the document to get the formatting to apply. It can take the place of up to 50 separate direct formatting settings. Using styles vastly simplifies a Word file.

**You can see this yourself if you unpack one of your Word documents.**

1. Make a copy.
2. Apply some formatting using a built-in style.
3. Apply some formatting using a custom style.
4. Then using the Body Text or normal style, apply direct formatting to achieve the
   same results.
5. Save your document as something like StylesTest.docx.
6. Then, close it and in Windows rename it Styles.Test.docx.zip and
   give permission for Windows to change the extension. You now have a
   zip folder.
7. Double-click to open that.
8. Examine the XML for the document.

Here is a [temporary link to a sample document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xt3bv960yokytru/stylestest.docx?dl=0).

Here is a screenshot from that document:
[image: screenshot from document]

Here is what the document XML looks like for these three paragraphs:
[image: screenshot of XML]

- Line 8 is the XML for the first paragraph.
- Line 11 is the XML for the second paragraph.
- Lines 13-21 are the XML for the third *(directly-formatted)* paragraph.

In a separate XML part you would find the definitions for the Styles. Here is the definition for the Style Body Text 3 used in the test document as the custom style.
[image: screenshot from XML of styles]

Here is the definition of the built-in Heading 1 style also used in the sample document.
[image: screenshot XML for Heading 1]

Look at the efficiency tests I refer to in [my page](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview).

Here are some more references:

- [Tips for Understanding Styles](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/styles/stylesms.html) by Shauna Kelly
- [Display, Use, and Manage Styles in Word](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP

Comment: Note that I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for this explanation. It's clear to me now. What I gotta do next is to look for a solution to convert style formation applied to direct formatting (if that's possible). Will post when I find something useful.

Comment: Look at @Rayearth's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This macro does the job of converting style formatting to direct formatting.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/how-can-i-removeconvert-styles-to-make-text-normal/b0ecb413-7d36-4643-bb34-0cd2cf08a9f3

Quoting from that answer:

> The only reasonable way to do this is with a macro. The following code
> (see http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm if needed) goes
> through the document one paragraph at a time. Wherever it finds a
> paragraph that isn't already in Normal style, it saves the character
> formatting and the paragraph formatting into variables, changes the
> style to Normal, and then applies the paragraph's original (style)
> formatting as direct formatting.

```
Sub DirectFormat()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim fnt As Font
    Dim pfmt As ParagraphFormat
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With para
            If .Style <> ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") Then
                Set fnt = .Style.Font
                Set pfmt = .Style.ParagraphFormat
                .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
                .Range.Font = fnt
                .Range.ParagraphFormat = pfmt
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

> If there was any direct formatting in these paragraphs at the start,
> that will be discarded (keeping it would be a lot more work). For your
> illustrative purpose, I don't think that will be a problem.

Jay Freedman, Word MVP - here is his [download page](http://jay-freedman.info/).